# can you force ios to launch safari other than any other browser or even give an option?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to launch safari only? I know in order to send an intent and have ios to handle it we can do `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];`, but if user has other browser installed (i.e. chrome), there's no guarantee safari will be used.

Reason I want to use safari is that I'm trying to have safari to handle certificate authentication for me, and according to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1745/_index.html), only system app has permission to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  //initially we need to check  safari is installed or not in our device
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"safari://"];
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([application canOpenURL:url]) {
   // if success again need to validate the our calling URL.
    NSURL *linkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://iostree.wordpress.com/2017/07/29/launch-safari-from-ios-app/"];
    if ([application canOpenURL:linkURL]) {
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
            [application openURL:linkURL options:@{}
               completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                   NSLog(@"success");
               }];
        }
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"safari is not installed");
}
```